# Android: When to start activity with . in Android Manifest?

Tags: java, android, class, android-manifest

Simple question: When do you have to start an activity or other class's name with a . in de Manifest file and why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` is just a shortcut for the package name for the application itself. When the activity is in another package, you need to use the fully qualified name. When the activity is in the same package (or a subpackage), the full package name can still be used, but the `.` is easier to read.

It seems that some versions of the build tools also prepend the app package name if the activity name has no `.` in it at all, but that is contrary to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm).

> The name of the class that implements the activity, a subclass of Activity. The attribute value should be a fully qualified class name (such as, "`com.example.project.ExtracurricularActivity`"). However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period (for example, "`.ExtracurricularActivity`"), it is appended to the package name specified in the `<manifest>` element.

Answer (score 3):

It's relative to the package name that you specify in the Manfiest.

If your activity is in `com.example.myActivityPackage` and in the Manifest you specify that your package is `com.example`, then the name you'd choose is `.myActivityPackage.myActivityClass`.

Likewise, if you had an activity that was in `completely.separate.package`, then you'd have to specify the whole thing as `completely.separate.package.activityClass`.

Answer (score 3):

in your manifest file simply . indicates your main package (which is launch first activity in your application) if your application include more than one package so for that class you have  to specified  `full package name . class name`.

Answer (score 1):

> However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period (for example ".ExtracurricularActivity"), it is appended to the package name specified in the .

From the Android source code, the period indicates that the Activity lives within your package.